# How can I validate, Number in range from 0 to 28 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to check, the number I am receiving should be in the range from 0 to 28 in Javascript.

I have code snippet like:

```
var letters = /[0-9]{1,2}/;
return letters.exec(value) != null;
```

Can you please help me in understanding what actually the above syntax doing, I can understand if the value obtained is null then it will return FALSE for sure, but I wanted to know what actually this regex is doing and how exec is working for the variable "letter".

Thanks in advance guys, please share if you have some other example.

Comment: Please don't tag your `javascript` questions with `java`. They are entirely different languages.

Comment: Try parsing it into a number with `parseInt` and doing `number >= 0 && number <= 28`

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Does it *really* have to be a regex?

Comment: Can you please help me in understanding what actually the above syntax doing, I can understand if the value obtained is null then it will return FALSE for sure, but I wanted to know what actually this regex is doing and how exec is working for variable letter. Thannks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I would say just a simple condition like

```
if(number >= 0 && number <= 28) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `if` statement and check if the values lies between 0 & 28

```js
function check() {
  let getIp = +document.getElementById('input').value;
  if (getIp <= 28 && getIp => 0) {
    alert('In range')
  }

}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input'>
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a regular expression solution then, you can use this: `/^([0-9]|[01][0-9]|2[0-8])$/`

Answer (score 0):

`.exec()` is actually javascript regexp object's method as `RegExp.prototype.exec()` and documented so nicely in mozila's [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) quoting it below:

> ### RegExp.prototype.exec()
>
> **Syntax:**
>
> *regexObj.exec(str)*
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> *str*
>
> The string against which to match the regular expression.
>
> **Return value:**
>
> If the **match succeeds, the exec() method returns an array and
>   updates the lastIndex property** of the regular expression object. The
>   returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one
>   item for each capturing parenthetical that matched containing the text
>   that was captured.
>
> If the **match fails, the exec() method returns null, and sets
>   lastIndex to 0**.

If you want to validate number is in range of 0 to 28 using `regex` then see below example:

```js
var letters = /^[0-9]$|^1[0-9]$|^2[0-8]$/;

function checkRange(regex,value){
 var msg = value;
 msg += (regex.exec(value) != null)?" is in range":" is not in range";
 msg += " of 0-28";
 console.log(msg) ;
}

checkRange(letters,20);
checkRange(letters,29);
```

i have provided above example to explain you the use of `.exec` but for checking number range using regex is memory overhead only.

**so i prefer to use simple `if` or `ternary` condition, because it is easy and provides simplicity and it works same in less code which is what every developer want.** :

```
//if condition
if(value >= 0 && value <= 28) { console.log('number is in range of 0-28'); } 

//ternary operator
var msg = (value >= 0 && value <= 28)?'number is in range of 0-28':'number is not in range of 0-28';
console.log(msg);
```